# How to correctly do error handling that involves asynchronous methods

Tags: scala

Suppose I have the following methods defined in some service used in my Play application each of which executes some command, on failure, updates database and sends some notification asynchronously.

`def thisMightFail(): Future[SomeResult]`

`def thisUpdatesStatus(): Future[Unit]`

`def thisSendsNotification(): Future[Unit]`

`thisUpdatesStatus` and `thisSendsNotification` are independent of each other and are called for error handling like the below. (No further execution is possible on failure)

```
for {
     _ <- Future{ Some process }
result <- thisMightFail() transform {
            case Success(v) => v
            case Failure(cause) => 
                val f = Future.sequence(List(
                thisUpdatesStatus(),
                thisSendsNotification()
             ))
             Failure(new Exception("Command execution failed", cause))
          }
     _ <- Future{ Another process that uses "result" }
             :
} yield ...
```

My question is should the `f`  be waited before returning `Failure(cause)` or is there some better way to handle the error in this kind of situation?

Comment: Thanks for great questions! Could you please clarify what is `f` in ```My question is should the f be waited``` sentence? Thank you!

Comment: To make sure that both methods are executed before returning `Failure`

Answer (score 0):

> My question is should the f be waited before returning Failure(cause)
>   or is there some better way to handle the error in this kind of
>   situation

Currently your code does not handle failure of `thisUpdatesStatus()` and `thisSendsNotification()`. are you ok with the failure of these functions call ? 
I suspect it will not be ok if `thisMightFail()` fails and you do not update the database. Also user should receive some notification if `thisMightFail()` fails.
You should use a workflow platform for such cases such as [cadence](https://cadenceworkflow.io/) . You can find a nice introduction of cadence [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llmsBGKOuWI).

Comment: Those methods are meant to be called on failure and the error handling of error handling is not taken into account here.

Comment: If you do not care about error handling of `thisUpdatesStatus()` and `thisSendsNotification()` then there is no point in waiting for `f`. Those two methods will start executing in two different threads and will finish as success or failure eventually.